# Python while loop iteration does not work

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, user-input, lis

I am a new one in Python programming and have not been able to solve the following problem for hours. I have sample file which contains four lines. I wish to get two inputs from user by the time it is found in the file line, however my loops do not seem to iterate over all the lines.This is the content of the file, elements are separated by a space:

```
Google 1 2  
Apple 13 17  
Microsoft 22 8  
Verizon 6 15
```

And this one is my code:

```
import sys
with open('manylines.txt','r') as myfile:
    results = [line.split() for line in myfile]

    for i in results:
        print(i)


        term1=input("Enter the first term:")
        while  term1 not in i :
            print("Term not found,please try again:")
            term1 = input("Enter the first term:")

        term2 = input("Enter the second term:")
        while term2 not in (i) :
            print("Term not found,please try again:")
            term2 = input("Enter the second term:")
        print(i)
        print(i)
        sys.exit()
```

I wish to input for example Google and Microsoft and get following output:

```
['Google','1','2']  
['Microsoft','22','8']
```

as two lists. However, my code only finds the first line and  not the others. Could you tell me why it does not iterate over other lines, please. How to fix this?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: what are your values for first term and second term?

Comment: Your calling `sys.exit` inside your for-loop, so the program will always terminate at the first iteration.

Comment: values are for example Google and Microsoft @lmiguelvargasf

Comment: try with `result = [line.split() for line in myfile.readlines()]`

Comment: The same thing  when I remove sys.exit()  @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @KaranChudasama no that is actually just a less efficient way to do that.

Comment: I tried, the same thing unfortunately @Karan Chudasama

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by "I wish to get two inputs from user by the time it is found in the file line". Especially the part starting "by the time...".

Comment: raw_input under `for i in results:` just a bad joke ! `def search(*args) : for i in results : ........`  every search need iterate whole data or result of results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that does not change the code from your attempt to drastically... It makes use of [`lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) and [`title()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) to allow for various capitalization's of user input:

```
import sys

with open('data.txt','r') as f:
    results = [line.split() for line in f]

while True:
    found = False
    term = input("Enter a company to search or type exit: ")
    if term.lower() == "exit":
        break
    for record in results:
        if record[0] == term.title():
            print(record)
            found = True
            break
    if not found:
        print("Term not found, please try again...")

print("Goodbye!")
sys.exit(0)
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Enter a company to search or type exit: Google
['Google', '1', '2']
Enter a company to search or type exit: microsoft
['Microsoft', '22', '8']
Enter a company to search or type exit: Amazon
Term not found, please try again...
Enter a company to search or type exit: Exit
Goodbye!
```

**Here is how you can only prompt the user for only "two terms":**

```
out1, out2 = [], []
term_count = 1
while term_count < 3:
    found = False
    term = input("Enter term %d or type exit: " % term_count)
    if term.lower() == "exit":
        break
    for record in results:
        if term_count == 1 and record[0] == term.title():
            print(record)
            out1 = list(record)
            found = True
            term_count += 1
            break
        if term_count == 2 and record[0] == term.title():
            print(record)
            out2 = list(record)
            found = True
            term_count += 1
            break
    if not found:
        print("Term not found, please try again...")
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Enter term 1 or type exit: Amazon
Term not found, please try again...
Enter term 1 or type exit: Google
['Google', '1', '2']
Enter term 2 or type exit: Microsoft
['Microsoft', '22', '8']
Goodbye!
```

Comment: Thank you so much @shash678 . One more thing I would like to ask. I wish to prompt only two inputs, as shown in my code. Could you show how to do that please ? I mean, one time it checks for two inputs and when it gets those two found items, it prints those two  appropriate lists as you have shown and program exits.Could you show this, please ?

Comment: Thank you @shash678 . Last thing I would like to ask.This is approximately what I look for but is it possible that, I assign two variables for them. I mean if Google found, assign the output ['Google', '1', '2'] to let us say to out1 and  assign Microsoft  output  ['Microsoft', '22', '8'] to out2. I mean I would like to get them as two lists and then to use those list in other parts of a program for further purposes. How could it be done ? I really appreciate your great help!

Comment: @python_beginner There you go edited the second code block to your specification now you can use out1 and out2 wherever you want :) Consider marking my answer as correct if you feel my answer was helpful :) –

Comment: Perfect, yes actually, I understood it. Thank you for the great help. Marked as best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. This code identifies which term is found and asks the term which is not found.

You are not making your loop properly. When your loop executes first time it has Google and term1 contains Google and term2 contains Microsoft. So it prints Google and after that you are stooping the execution using **sys.exit()**. So of course it prints the first line not the others.

```
import sys
with open('tempa.txt','r') as myfile:
    results = [line.split() for line in myfile]

NeedToExecute = 0
term1 = False
term2 = False

list1 = None
list2 = None

while NeedToExecute != 2:

    if(term1 != True):
        term1 = input("Enter the first term:")

    if(term2 != True):
        term2 = input("Enter the second term:")

    for i in results:

        if term1 in i :
            NeedToExecute = NeedToExecute + 1
            term1 = True
            list1 = i
            print(i)

        if term2 in i :
            NeedToExecute = NeedToExecute + 1
            term2 = True
            list2 = i
            print(i)

print list1
print list2
```

Comment: Thanks @Ujjaval Moradiya for your answer. But could you tell me how can I assign two variables for those two list. Let us say the first one becomes list1 and the second one is list2. I wish to use those lists for further purposes in my program. Thank you really for the help!

Comment: Yes you can do that. Why aren't you thinking for the same. It is not that difficult. Check my updated code

Comment: Yes, I understood it, defining the lists and then adding results there. Thank you very much for great help!